# Breadcrumbs with Zend_Navigation and character encoding

Tags: zend-framework, character-encoding

I'm developing a website with brazilian characters using Zend Framework and my navigation menu items are inside a database.

I've double checked my character encoding in the HTML meta tag, in the files itself and my database. Everything is set to UTF-8 and my whole website is rendering fine (including my menu items which has accented character.

AlthoughI'm using Zend_Navigation for rendering a breadcrumb and it's not going very well. See the image below:

[image]

`Miss&atilde;o` is what I have in my database. Unfortunately, it's not becoming `ã` instead. I don't know why.

---

I'm also using Zend_Navigation in my admin module for both Breadcrumb and Menu which render perfectly. The difference is that I'm using a XML in my admin module and Arrays in my default module (which is the problematic one).

I tried to write the XML from the Config object using Zend_Config_Writer_Xml. Then, I checked the file and it was written correctly: `<label>Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es</label>`. Although, in order to the XML render correctly, it's enough to write just `<label>Informações</label>` (that's what I have in the admin module navigation XML).

Well, what if I write `Informações` directly in the array then ask it to write the XML? I tried this and I got `<label>Informa&#xE7;&#xF5;es</label>` which doesn't work, also.

I'd like to come up with a solution 'cause I'm running out of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the breadcrumb helper is escaping the output automatically. [There is a hardcoded call to `escape()` in `renderStraight()`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/Breadcrumbs.php). You can verify by looking at the sourcecode and see if the `&` is an `&amp;`.

If you are already using UTF-8, you should not use entities for your special chars. Just use their regular representation. To get around XML converting it to entities [make sure the XML file is set to write UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575109/php-using-domdocument-whenever-i-try-to-write-utf-8-it-writes-the-hexadecimal-no/3575326#3575326).

If all that doesnt help, [check that the webserver is serving the Response in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095058/browser-displays-instead-of/4095089#4095089). Meta Tags are just fallbacks and won't be considered if the Webserver sends an encoding. Although this is unlikely the reason if other entities show fine.