# Search and replace in MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, browser, character-encoding, special-characters

I have an unusual problem (this is linked to [Browser displays � instead of ´](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095058/browser-displays-instead-of))

I had mismatched character encoding settings on my server (UTF-8) and application (ISO-8859-1), so a third person tasked with entering Spanish translations, entered the words properly at his end, but they weren't saved correctly in the database.

I have subsequently fixed the problem and the server is now ISO-8859-1 as well. [I set

```
default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
```

in php.ini]

I do see a pattern in what is in the system, for example the following appears on the system:

```
Nombre de la organizaciÃ³n*
```

This needs to be:

```
Nombre de la organización*
```

ie, I need to search and replace 'Ã³' with 'ó'.

How can I do so for an entire table (all fields)? (there will be other such corrections as well)

Comment: You'd be best off setting everything to UTF-8, rather than ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Alex JL: Good advice. However, the question refers to finding and replacing some text from all the rows of a field (or more fields) in a table.

Comment: @matt: I'm puzzled about that "all fields". You probably have a primary key, so you don't need this replace to happen at all fields. Maybe you've meant all rows/records? (If you meant that, then my answer contains the solution)

Comment: @matt74tm because it will handle all the character from IS-8859-1, and then some.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad right, that's  why it was a comment and not an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the replace function. Simple example:

```
SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');
```

Result: 'WwWwWw.mysql.com'

Now, if you have a table called Foo and you want to replace those characters in a field called bar, you can do the following:

```
update Foo set bar = Replace(bar, 'Ã³', 'ó');
```

Do this for all the affected fields and the problem is solved.

Best regards,
Lajos Arpad.