# PDO + MySQL and broken UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, character-encoding

I use the PDO library with a MySQL database in PHP, but if I insert any data encoded in UTF-8, like Arabic words, it’s inserted into the database, but as `?????????`.

In my own framework, after I create the PDO connection, I send two queries – `SET NAMES utf8` and `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`. It still doesn’t work.

Example:

```
loadclass('PDO', array(
    sprintf(
        'mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s',
        confitem('database', 'host'),
        confitem('database', 'port'),
        confitem('database', 'name')
    ),
    confitem('database', 'username'),
    confitem('database', 'password'),
    array('PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT' => confitem('database', 'pconnect'))
));
$this->query('SET NAMES ' . confitem('database', 'charset'));
$this->query('SET CHARACTER SET ' . confitem('database', 'charset'));
```

Workaround: Use the `json_encode` function to convert data before inserting it to the database, and use `json_decode` to decode it after fetching. This is how I do it now.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't PHP's problem?  Make sure you have mbstring installed?

Comment: I'd suggest to send back the same string and check if it arrives ok. Just as a test.

Comment: what is confitem('database','charset') value?

Comment: Col. Shrapnel : result for confitem('database','charset') is UTF8

Answer (score 150, accepted):

> **Warning:** This answer applies to PHP 5.3.5 and lower. Do not use it for PHP version 5.3.6 (released in March 2011) or later.
>
> Compare with [Palec's answer *here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21373793/367456).

---

Use:

```
$pdo = new PDO( 
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName', 
    'username', 
    'password', 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") 
);
```

It forces UTF-8 on the PDO connection. It worked for me.

Comment: if you have PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES 'UTF8'' --  make sure you do not have added : ->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8") ...

Comment: You have to enable it using extension=intl or extension=php_intl.dll

Comment: Nice. If you're getting NULL results in PHP but perfectly fine results in your MySQL client using the same SQL it's likely this. Problem solved the moment I added your solution .

Comment: See the answer from Palec, charset=utf8 usually is the better method.

Comment: I now also put a warning in there. It might have been good in 2011, but not the last couple of years. /cc @ArtGeigel

Comment: What about php 8.1, there I get "Uncaught TypeError: Attribute value must be of type int for selected attribute, string given" for "array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8')".

Answer (score 73):

You have to set the correct character set for the connection. [Add the `charset=utf8` option to the DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) (this is MySQL-specific!)

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName;charset=utf8',
    'username',
    'password'
);
```

However, in PHP versions *before* 5.3.6 (released in March 2011), you must use a workaround as the `charset` option in the DSN is not supported.

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName',
    'username',
    'password',
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
```

Comment: Wanted to update the existing, top-voted answer, but [my edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3904725). Therefore posting it as a new answer.

Comment: Thank you! `charset=utf8'` Work for me on Datatable server side

Comment: Thanks for this! charset=utf8 was what sorted this very annoying issue for me as well.

Comment: Could you just do both, or would that cause side effects? In other words why not just always set the charset in the connection string and pass that SET NAMES option as well?

Answer (score 4):

All attempts like:

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' "
```

or

```
$this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME.';charset=utf8', DBUSER, DBPASS, self::$opt);
```

or

```
$this->connection->exec("set names utf8");
```

still generated unreadable text mess.

In my case, the cause of the problem was: `htmlentities` used prior to inserting data into a database.
**Cyrillic letters** were destroyed completely.

Comment: You can pass an encoding of 'UTF-8' to htmlentities as the third parameter: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `default_charset` value in php.ini to UTF-8. Or you can set it using the [ini_set](https://www.php.net/function.ini_set) function.

Also, if the input is coming through form submissions, make sure your web pages are set to UTF-8 using the meta tag.

Comment: hello , ok i will try , but i don't neeed this solve , i want solve it from my script :) ?

Comment: yes .. i tested data coming from web pages , yes it coming with utf-8 enconding , and there is a utf-8 encoding meta tag

Comment: I just had the same issue on the Windows machine, and this was the solution to the problem. Everything was talking UTF-8... except PHP.

Answer (score 0):

When interacting with mysql or mariadb, charset 'utf8' is not correct. You need to use utf8mb4. Due to historical issues, utf8 in mysql/mariadb is an alias to utf8mb3 which can only contain a subset of utf8 (3 bytes instead of 4)
So adding 'charset=utf8mb4' to your PDO DSN connection string is the correct thing to do for recent PHP versions, NOT charset=utf8.

For example, the poop emoji in full color:  cannot be stored if the column and PDO are not utf8mb4.