# How do i have a SQL query with UTF-8 chars in?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8, pdo

```
<?php 
    $path               = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kanjisearch;charset=utf-8";
    $pdo                = new PDO($path, "xxx", "xxx");
    $sth                = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `kanji` WHERE `kanjiName` = '$kanji'");
    $sth->execute();
    $results            = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

I am building a PHP search that uses Chinese characters in the actual SQL query, I have -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); on the pdo. And it renders just fine, the text I bring back renders the charects great, if I put numbers ins the sql but I need to search based on the Kanji, so when I query with WHERE kanji = 一, the 一 doesn't seem to go through ok, it renders on the screen on the debug, but just wont query, results return empty but when I copy the query directly into PHPMyAdmin it returns the result.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM  `kanji` 
WHERE  `kanjiName` =  '一' 
In the in PHPMyAdmin works just fine. However this does not,
SELECT * FROM  `kanji` WHERE  `kanjiName` =  '$kanji' 
and its the same thing

Comment: Probably you need `SET NAMES utf8` [as described in PDO manual](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php). Before PHP 5.3.6 the `charset` parameter in DNS was ignored. Well, now I noticed you specify `utf-8`. Try changing it to `utf8` (remove the hyphen). MySQL does not like the hyphenated form.

Comment: What is the definition of `kanji.kanjiName` column? What is the charset and collation of the `kanji` table? Why don’t you prepare the query with `WHERE kanjiName = ?`? Then you would supply `$kanji` in `$sth->ececute($kanji)`. Is `$kanji` really encoded in UTF-8?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try add encoding (accept-charset="UTF-8" and charset=utf-8") to your form and html head:

```
<form method="post" action="yourAction" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

EDIT: also have a look at this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475548/pdomysql-and-utf-8-encoding-problem). (by shark555)

```
$pdo = new PDO( 
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName', 
    'username', 
    'password', 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") 
);
```

Comment: I know this part, this part is easy that just parsing it to the page. But once on the search in need PHP to send the SQL query

Comment: This is not the same as my question at all, he is asking about rendering, mine renders just fine. It just does not query with these chars.

Comment: Sorry for doubting you dude, I read the article more and yes this was the right thing, first time I just copied and pasted it. Got to learn to read more, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Were your tables and or columns created with the UTF-8 character set as the default encoding? By default MySQL creates tables with a latin based charset and collate options. UTF-8, especially none latiin characters, gets mangled when it is saved in a latin encoded column.

Try changing the table's charset to use UTF8 using the ALTER table command and reloading/inserting your data.

Comment: The tables are in UTF-8

Comment: What happens if you pass $kanji as a param instead of interpolatiing it as a string?                                                        $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `kanji` WHERE `kanjiName` =?");
$sth->execute($kanji);

Comment: I did think that too, No joy.

Answer (score -1):

$kanji needs to be handled as a particular/specific character set.
so, what's typed in is likely not seen as a UTF-8 encoded string. you need to handle this.

note: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4e00/index.htm

basically you want to convert to UTF-8. but try this:
https://www.php.net/mb_convert_encoding

like

- mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8');
- or if you know the encoding of the language stick as the 3rd param.
- or try auto: mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'auto');