# Doctrine2 and UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, doctrine

Hey everybod out there :)
I'm using CodeIgniter and Doctrine2 as my ORM.
I'm having problem with storing and retrieving UTF-8 texts from my database.

I've red something about PostConnection Events but im not really sure where to add this stuff :/

My Database and the tables have UTF-8 Encoding.

Can some tell me how i can fix this? :)

greetings

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078786/showing-instead-of/5078800#5078800

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell your entityManager explicitly you want to use UTF-8. You don't show any code, so I just give you my snippet:

```
// $entityManager is an instance of EntityManager
// Add UTF8 handler to EntityManager
$entityManager->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber(
                new \Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\MysqlSessionInit('utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci')
);
```

This worked for me. Also, make sure you only use multibyte functions of PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

Comment: As the MysqlSessionInit is used I supose the solution works just for MySQL database, doesn't it?

Comment: @PetrPeller, yeah, this is strictly MySQL related.